# Is there a way to redirect non www to www only on HTTP but not HTTPS?

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect

is it possible to do as following with .htaccess:

```
http://example.com redirecting to http://www.example.com
```

but...

```
https://www.example.com redirecting to https://example.com
```

And http not redirecting to https.

So basically keep www on HTTP but no www on HTTPS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't seem to be working (I cleared my cache and cookie)...

Comment: Both rules work fine on my Apache. Make sure your .htaccess is enabled and these 2 rules are just below `RewriteEngine On` line

Comment: Ok as I didn't install SSL on www, I guess the security warning message appears before the redirection. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes that's right. SSL cert is presented before mod_rewrite rules.